# Facebook API does not allow this. So how does Hotmail get email and phone number of friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

From what I can see so far, the facebook API does not allow you to extract the email address and phone number of your friends - it just returns an empty/null string. If that is the case, how does Hotmail/ Windows Live Mail do it? It allows you to import all of your contacts from facebook, including their email address and phone numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo and Hotmail have special agreements in place with Facebook to allow syncing with your webmail account. Regular facebook applications don't ever allow access to friend email addresses, only the current users if email permissions are granted.